# How to achieve row span in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I want to achieve row span in the SSRS. I want to achieve following layout.
[image]

How i can achieve? 
I have tried by using matrix but it is doing the row span only for first column but i want row span for middle columns also.

Can anyone help me for this?